# Check if other app running via windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have windows service wrote in C# , where I need to check couple of apps is running or not

For example if Skype running, I need to find it process and write in Console log -  "Skype app is running"

I wondering how to do this, because can't find any related info in google?

Comment: Google did not find [Process.GetProcessByName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname?view=netframework-4.8) ?

Comment: @Fildor It's better to search by name or PID?

Comment: Do you know the PID?

Comment: I can search it via `tasklist /svc` or it can be changed  on different PC's? @Fildor

Comment: The PID is not unique per Application but per running process. It will also be different if you kill an app and start it again.

Comment: Okay, so will search by name. Thnk's @Fildor

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy google search away from getting an answer...

Just a little FYI, skype is always running I think... might have to close down the service to have it not run... so to make the example work for me :P I just use notepad in the example

```
var runningProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();

if (runningProcesses.Any(p => p.ProcessName.Contains("notepad", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
    Console.WriteLine("Notepad is running");

Console.Read();
```